# Install swift 4 on bash on Ubuntu on Windows 10

Tags: swift, windows, ubuntu

I try to install Swift 4 on bash on Ubuntu on Windows 10

My version of Ubuntu:

`me@DESKTOP:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial`

I did `apt-get upgrade` and `apt-get update`

I follow Linux steps [here:](https://swift.org/download/#using-downloads) to install Swift 4

Eventually I end up with the error:

`me@DESKTOP:~$ swift
/home/me/swift4/swift-4.0.2-RELEASE-ubuntu16.04/usr/bin/lldb: error while loading shared libraries: libpython2.7.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I have python2 installed:

`me@DESKTOP:~$ python2 --version
Python 2.7.12`

I wonder how to make it works.

Comment: Please run the following and paste the results: locate libpython2.7.so.1.0

Comment: locate libpython2.7.so.1.0 returns nothing

Comment: That's a problem. I was expecting a mismatch between the location and the LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Will you try the locate command on a file you know exists to ensure it works? I think /etc/updatedb.conf has tags PRUNEPATHS and PRUNF or something similar that may exclude directories on locate.

Comment: Try to run this: `sudo updatedb`

Comment: That should update the updatedb.conf. Afterwards, try `locate` again please.

Comment: Actually, the bash on Ubuntu 16 on Windows is a total mess. I found a lot of other issues, including **Illegal instruction (core dumped)**, with my Swift 4 installation. I gave up on trying to make it work and switched to Ubuntu 16 on Virtual Box and it really works.

Answer (score 0):

Installing `libpython2.7` successfully resolves the error

```
$ apt-get install libpython2.7
```

However it still failed to launch the swift repl due to [kernel permissions issue](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-54?focusedCommentId=23856&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-23856).
Using [docker image](https://github.com/IBM-Swift/swift-ubuntu-docker) (or Virtual Box like OP) is a better way to go.

### reference

https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2743